# SELINUX : How to make child folder rule precedence higher than parent rule

Tags: linux, centos, file-permissions, selinux

SELINUX : How to make child folder rule precedence higher than parent rule
eg :

/home/kevinw/www/kp/storage(/.*)?                  all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0

**lost to** /home/kevinw/www(/.*)?                  all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0

Or my concept are wrong as it already set on the parent?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, by default we can force restore the child folder to not follow the parent folder

`restorecon -RFv /path/to/folder`

or using `chcon`